# Compatibility between gRPC and protobuf versions

Tags: c++, grpc

I would like to know if gRPC is attached to a specific version of protobuffer.

I mean, when I compile gRPC from source in the C++ git repository, the [third_party](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/third_party) folder contains a submodule linked to the protobuffer repo. Could I use any other version of the protobuf library other than the one attached by default?